# Does import with wildcard behave differently with user package

Tags: java

```
 //With these I am getting compilation - error class not found 
 /*import Shape.TwoD.*;
 import Shape.ThreeD.*;
 import Shape.*;*/

 import Shape.TwoD.Circle;
 import Shape.TwoD.Line;
 import Shape.ThreeD.Line3D;
 import Shape.ThreeD.Sphere;
 import Shape.Actions;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>Test</code>.
     */
     int o;
    public Test() {

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Actions obj[] = new Actions[4];
        obj[0] = new Line(1,2,3,4);
        obj[1] = new Circle(1,2,3);
        obj[2] = new Line3D(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        obj[3] = new Sphere(1,2,3,4);
        for(Actions x: obj)
            x.draw();
        Actions.TwoD o =(Circle)obj[1];
        System.out.println("Area of circle "+o.area());
        o = (Sphere)obj[3];
        System.out.println("Volume of sphere "+o.area());
    }
}
```

`Action` is an interface which contains nested interface `TwoD` and `ThreeD`

Why import with wildcard not working in the above code? Am I using it wrong?

I couldn't find any related answer, if both wildcard and fully qualified imports are not working then there is problem in my code but in this case, compilation error occur `class not found` only when I use wildcard with import.

EDIT:
Sorry for the wrong naming convention, `Line`,`Circle`,`Line3D` and `Sphere` are the classes 
`Line`and `Circle` comes under `Shape.TwoD`

`Line3D` and `Sphere` comes under `Shape.ThreeD`

Actions.java:

package Shape;

```
public interface Actions {

        interface ThreeD{
            double volume();
        }

        interface TwoD{
            double area();
        }

        void draw();
        //void erase();
        final double pi = 3.142857;

}
```

Line.java:

```
    package Shape.TwoD;

public class Line implements Shape.Actions{

    BaseObj.Point p1,p2;

    public Line(int x1,int y1, int x2 ,int y2) {
        p1 = new BaseObj.Point(x1,y1);
        p2 = new BaseObj.Point(x2,y2);
    }

    public void draw(){
        //System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.x+","+p1.y+") and ("+p2.x+","+p2.y+"));
        System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.getx()+","+p1.gety()+") and ("+p2.getx()+","+p2.gety()+") has been drawn");
    }

}
```

Circle.java:

```
package Shape.TwoD;

public class Circle extends BaseObj.Point implements Shape.Actions, Shape.Actions.TwoD{

    protected int radius;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
        super(x,y);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Circle with ("+x+","+y+") as center and radius "+radius+" units has been drawn");
    }

    public double area(){
        return (pi*radius*radius);
    }

}
```

Line3D.java:

```
package Shape.ThreeD;
public class Line3D  implements Shape.Actions {

    BaseObj.Point3D p1,p2;

    public Line3D(int x1,int y1, int z1, int x2,int y2, int z2) {
        p1 = new BaseObj.Point3D(x1,y1,z1);
        p2 = new BaseObj.Point3D(x2,y2,z2);
    }

    public void draw(){
        //System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.x+","+p1.y+") and ("+p2.x+","+p2.y+"));
        System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.getx()+","+p1.gety()+","+p1.getz()+") and ("+p2.getx()+","+p2.gety()+","+p2.getz()+") has been drawn");
    }

}
```

Sphere.java:

```
package Shape.ThreeD;
public class Sphere extends Shape.TwoD.Circle{

    int z;

    public Sphere(int x, int y, int z, int radius) {
        super(x,y,radius);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Spere with ("+x+","+y+","+z+") as center and radius "+radius+" units has been drawn");
    }

    public double volume(){
        return(radius*radius*pi*4/3);
    }

    public double area(){
        System.out.println("Sphere is a 3D object so 2D quantitys doesnt apply");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**
After correcting the names I got error that `Actions` interface is duplicate so I changed its name into `ObjActions` and the problem resolved. Thanks for the help. I hope the naming convention I used below is consistent with standard.

ObjActions.java

```
package shape;

public interface ObjActions {

        interface Actions3D{
            double volume();
        }

        interface Actions2D{
            double area();
        }

        void draw();
        //void erase();
        final double pi = 3.142857;

}
```

Circle.java

```
package shape.twod;

public class Circle extends baseobj.Point implements shape.ObjActions, shape.ObjActions.Actions2D{

    protected int radius;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
        super(x,y);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Circle with ("+x+","+y+") as center and radius "+radius+" units has been drawn");
    }

    public double area(){
        return (pi*radius*radius);
    }

}
```

Line.java

```
package shape.twod;

public class Line implements shape.ObjActions{

    baseobj.Point p1,p2;

    public Line(int x1,int y1, int x2 ,int y2) {
        p1 = new baseobj.Point(x1,y1);
        p2 = new baseobj.Point(x2,y2);
    }

    public void draw(){
        //System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.x+","+p1.y+") and ("+p2.x+","+p2.y+"));
        System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.getx()+","+p1.gety()+") and ("+p2.getx()+","+p2.gety()+") has been drawn");
    }

}
```

Line3D.java

```
package shape.threed;

public class Line3D  implements shape.ObjActions {

    baseobj.Point3D p1,p2;

    public Line3D(int x1,int y1, int z1, int x2,int y2, int z2) {
        p1 = new baseobj.Point3D(x1,y1,z1);
        p2 = new baseobj.Point3D(x2,y2,z2);
    }

    public void draw(){
        //System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.x+","+p1.y+") and ("+p2.x+","+p2.y+"));
        System.out.println("Line between ("+p1.getx()+","+p1.gety()+","+p1.getz()+") and ("+p2.getx()+","+p2.gety()+","+p2.getz()+") has been drawn");
    }

}
```

Sphere.java

```
package shape.threed;

public class Sphere extends shape.twod.Circle implements shape.ObjActions.Actions3D{

    int z;

    public Sphere(int x, int y, int z, int radius) {
        super(x,y,radius);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Spere with ("+x+","+y+","+z+") as center and radius "+radius+" units has been drawn");
    }

    public double volume(){
        return(radius*radius*pi*4/3);
    }

}
```

Test.java

```
package test;

 import shape.twod.*;
 import shape.threed.*;
 import shape.*;


 /*import shape.twod.Circle;
 import shape.twod.Line;
 import shape.threed.Line3D;
 import shape.threed.Sphere;
 import shape.Actions;*/

public class Test {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>Test</code>.
     */
     int o;
    public Test() {

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ObjActions obj[] = new ObjActions[4];
        obj[0] = new Line(1,2,3,4);
        obj[1] = new Circle(1,2,3);
        obj[2] = new Line3D(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        obj[3] = new Sphere(1,2,3,4);
        for(ObjActions x: obj)
            x.draw();
        ObjActions.Actions2D o =(Circle)obj[1];
        //Actions2D o =(Circle)obj[1];
        System.out.println("Area of circle "+o.area());
        ObjActions.Actions3D op = (Sphere)obj[3];
        System.out.println("Volume of sphere "+op.volume());
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java classes are in `PascalCase` packages as in `loweralpha`. This convention is **never diverged from**. I cannot tell whether you have packages, nested classes or something else entirely. Therefore I cannot answer your question.

Comment: So `Shape` is a class in the same (default) package? Btw using the default package is discouraged so I'd change that.

Comment: The point was, are `Shape`, `TwoD`, and `ThreeD` also classes, as the initial uppercase letter would suggest, or are they packages, in which case they should be named `shape`, `twod`, and `threed`?

Comment: Wait, `Action.TwoD` is an interface and `Shape.TwoD` is a package? You should _definitely_ work on your naming scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "packages" `TwoD` and `ThreeD` might get shadowed by the interfaces `Action.TwoD` and `Action.ThreeD` (or vice versa) as per [JLS 7.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2):

> The declaration might be shadowed by a single-type-import declaration of a type whose simple name is Vector; by a type named Vector and declared in the package to which the compilation unit belongs; or any nested classes or interfaces.
>
> The declaration might be obscured by a declaration of a field, parameter, or local variable named Vector.
>
> *(It would be unusual for any of these conditions to occur.)*

Comment: I changed `Action.TwoD` to `Action.TwoDActions` and `Action.ThreeD` to `Action.ThreeDActions` cleaned and rebuilded still getting`.\Test.java:34: error: cannot access Actions
        Actions obj[] = new Actions[4];
        ^
  bad source file: .\Actions.java
    file does not contain class Actions
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error`

Comment: @Sab _please_ read what multiple people have already stated and start by fixing your package naming. Doing that might solve your problems already but if not it will at least help people understand what you're doing. The more effort it takes to understand your question the less people will be willing to help.

Comment: +1 Thanks, figured out issue when I corrected naming conventions, should I post changed code as answer. I don't want to edit the code in question?

Comment: @Sab just add it to your question. That way it'll be right at the top for others to see.